# changing ObjectiveLimit option in fminunc in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, optimization

I have a noisy picture that I want to denoise, with specific energy function, my function have 3 free variable which I can change them until the energy function converge to the minimum value,I found values of these 3 variable by testing different value and run the program, but I want to know how can I find them by a good optimization algorithm. as far as I know I can use `fminunc` function in matlab but it gives me an error:

> fminunc stopped because the objective function value is less than or equal to the default value of the objective function limit.

`h`,`beta`,`v` is the 3 variable which initialize by `h=0.8`,`beta=4`,`v=0.9`

here is the enrgy formula

[image]

and also my code:

```
load Input_images.mat;

X=noisyImg();
Z=X;
[n,m]=size(Z);
c=1;

for c=1:5
    c
for i=1:n
    for j=1:m
        [neighbours] = neighbour(i,j,n,m,Z);

        sumneighpos=sum(Z(i,j)*neighbours(1,:)');
        inputnoisypos=(Z(i,j)*X(i,j));
        noisyzpos=h*Z(i,j);
        sumpos=noisyzpos-(beta*sumneighpos)-(v*inputnoisypos);
        sumneg=-sumpos;
        if sumneg<sumpos
           Z(i,j)=-Z(i,j);
        end
    end
 end
end
```

code for the optimization part.

```
f = @(q,w) h*Z(i,j)-q*sumneighpos-w*inputnoisypos;
fun = @(x) f(x(1),x(2));
x0 = [0.9; 4];
options = optimoptions('fminunc','Algorithm','quasi-newton');
[x, fval, exitflag, output] = fminunc(fun,x0,options);
```

here I have 2 question how can I fix the error and second one, is there any better algorithm?

Comment: What is your `exitflag`? It may be that you have reached a local minimum, see [When the Solver Might Have Succeeded](https://mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/when-the-solver-might-have-succeeded.html)